# Getting facebook user id using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook login at my app, and I was able to get neccesery information about logged in user (first and last name, id. gender etc..) so I can open a specific profile with that id. since I'm working with the latest facebook SDK I'm not able to get the user id.

I've noticed that there are few changes in this SDK but the issue that the only thing that I'm missing now is the user id. I can get the other information except the id - it gives me a wrong id (17 digits).

When I check it through the browser (using graph instead www) I can see that the user id including only 10 digits.

Here's the code:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        RequestAsyncTask request = Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,  new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                   if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            user_ID = user.getId();//user id
                            profileName = user.getName();//user's profile name
                            token = session.getAccessToken();
                            .
                            .
                            .
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        .
                        .
                        }
                    }
            }
        }); 
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the upgrade of facebook SDK to graph API v2.0.
Facebook gives a unique ID for users, changing between apps, which means that the given ID is not the original user id.

[Facebook reference:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api)

> **Changes from v1.0 to v2.0**
>
> App-scoped User IDs: To better protect people's information, when
>   people log into a version of your app that has been upgraded to use
>   Graph API v2.0, Facebook will now issue an app-scoped ID rather than
>   that person's orginal ID.

My solution is using the browser and not facebook application.
The url should look like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/GivenUserId
```

and the code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/"+userid)));
```